# PHP Any vulnerabilities in user input to Web Server running apache and PHP

Tags: php, webserver

There is understandably a lot of emphasis on sanitizing user input handed off to PHP on a Web Server and numerous opinions on doing it.

Can someone please confirm there is no security problems with the following PHP code which may compromise the server through an exploit:

```
if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == "kjg68KGH$88@kjhik8768"){
   $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']=NULL;
   do stuff
} else {
   $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']=NULL;
   do other stuff
}
```

or

```
if($_POST['the-var'] == "kjg68KGH$88@kjhik8768"){
   $_POST=[];
   do stuff
} else {
  $_POST=[];
  do other stuff
}
```

If there is ( I do not see how there could be) then why? Thankyou.

Comment: Looks more like a http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ question.

Comment: If you just treat user input as a string, and don't do anything that executes the contents, it can't become an exploit.

Comment: @Barmar, I agree totaly with U on that observation, however nothing amazes me anymore, so I just wanted some extra confirmation :)

Comment: CodeReview.SE or Security.SE might be better places to ask questions like this.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks - I have done so and on server fault also but it was flagged off topic on SF